# Xamarin Forms - Android - initialize libraries in splash activity (before main activity)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-context

My splash screen is Lottie animation, during 3-sec animation I am trying to initialize all I can in the background thread, so I put everything from MainActivity before LoadApplication method in this new activity, just wanted to put everything I can inside splash animation time

here is my splash activity class

```
[Activity(Label = "MyName", Theme = "@style/MyName.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, IAnimatorListener
{
    private Com.Airbnb.Lottie.LottieAnimationView animationView;
    public void OnAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
    {
    }

    public void OnAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
    {
        //StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)));
        Finish(); //if I remove this I got 1-2 sec white screen
    }

    public async void OnAnimationStart(Animator animation)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            OneSignal.Current.StartInit(API_KEY).InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification).EndInit();
            FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer: true);
            
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this); // ------ this became problem 

            MainActivity.AppInstance = new App(); //even create Xam App here but don't show it yet
        });
    }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashLayout);
        animationView = FindViewById<Com.Airbnb.Lottie.LottieAnimationView>(Resource.Id.animation_view);
        animationView.AddAnimatorListener(this);
    }

}
```

I put init methods inside the background thread because if it is on the main thread my animation is not fluid.
After the animation ends, I start main activity and show my app

main activity code

```
[Activity(Label = "MyName", Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static App AppInstance; //Xamarin App instance created on splash activity

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LoadApplication(AppInstance);
        AppInstance.Show(); //just setting MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

everything is working fine, except Rg plugin

if I move  `Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);` into main activity then it's working.

So my question is am I doing wrong to initialize platform-specific libraries in splash activity, and I why only Rg plugin doesn't work I see in init it asks for Context same as other libraries so I did initialize it with `this` keyword and starting main activity with `this` keyword

Should I do it some other way, init libraries while my animation is playing, because every sec counts when you start the application.

Context which Main activity is created is it different one from splash activity?
I even tried to replace all `this` with `Application.Context`

Comment: *"because every sec counts when you start the application."* - But every millisecond, not so much. When you put timing calls before and after that init line, how many milliseconds pass?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve when checked with stopwatch class everything that is working during my animation in the background took 2379 ms (MainActivity.AppInstance = new App() ) is 1600 ms that's why I moved initialization of the Xamarin app to my background thread while the animation is running

Comment: Yes of course.  So moving all that stuff made sense. But the Init you are asking about took how much of that?  My guess is 1 or 2 ms. Its easy enough for you to find out. If necessary, call it AGAIN in the Main Activity - I think you can do so without problem (though I have not tested).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes I agree and I moved it to the main activity and its working it's like few ms but my question was why is that not working, what happened with Context, and maybe some other libraries won't work like OneSingal or maybe FFImageLoadingForms too ... do you suggest to put all in Main Activity except new App() ?

Comment: Now I understand. I would do exactly what you did - only put into Main what seems to matter. Its easy enough to make a `public const bool OPTIMIZE_STARTUP = true;`  When false, have it do everything in Main. So if you suspect a problem, you can easily determine if it was due to moving that stuff.

Comment: I don't know what exactly changes in Context when a new Activity starts. You could make a small repo that shows the problem, and open an issue at `https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup`. Maybe its easy for someone to fix. OR maybe you'll get a reply that will be informative re whether this is simply a bad idea..